# How to insert value to a 2 dimensions array from a 1 dimension array using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say we have two arrays

```
a = [1, 2]

b = [ [A, B, C], [D, E, F] ]
```

I want to make `c = [ [1,A, B, C], [2, D, E, F] ]` by combing a & b

How to achieve that?

The amounts of 1st level children are the same in both a and b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) `a` so it becomes a 2x1 array then you can use [`hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) to horizontally stack the arrays:

```
In[13]:
np.hstack([a.reshape((2,1)), b])

Out[13]: 
array([['1', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
       ['2', 'D', 'E', 'F']], 
      dtype='<U11')
```

As suggested by numpy master @Divakar, if you slice the array and pass `None` as one of the axes, you can introduce or reshape the array without the need to `reshape`:

```
In[14]:
np.hstack([a[:,None], b])

Out[14]: 
array([['1', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
       ['2', 'D', 'E', 'F']], 
      dtype='<U11')
```

It's explained in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html), look for `newaxis` example

Comment: To make it generic : `a[:,None]`.

Comment: or `a.reshape(-1, 1)` if you feel `reshape` is clearer

Comment: @DanielF I generally prefer explicit code so it's clearer IMO, depends on how well seasoned you are with numpy to know what passing `-1` will do

Answer (score 0):

You could use `zip` and a list comprehension:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
c = [[e] + l for e, l in zip(a, b)]
print(c) #=> [[1, 'a', 'b', 'c'], [2, 'd', 'e', 'f']]
```